Using Try/Catch for PowerShell to switch between the two cmdlet gro group member?
Using PowerShell script If Else or Try catch, how can I modify the below script, if the Group member type = Computer, then use Get-MGDevice to display the display name.
$GROUP_LIST = Get-MgGroup -Filter "groupTypes/any(c:c eq 'DynamicMembership')" -All:$true | Select-Object Id, DisplayName, Description, GroupTypes

$users = $GROUP_LIST | ForEach-Object {
    $Group = $_
    Write-Host "Processing $($Group.DisplayName)" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    $members = Get-MgGroupMember -GroupId $Group.Id -Property "id,displayName,userPrincipalName,companyName"

    Write-Host "`t [$($Group.DisplayName)] Member count [$($members.Count)]" -ForegroundColor Yellow

    $members | ForEach-Object {
        $member = $_
        Try {
            $user = Get-MgUser -UserId $member.Id -Property Id, DisplayName, Mail, UserPrincipalName, CompanyName | 
                    Select-Object Id, DisplayName, Mail, UserPrincipalName, CompanyName

            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Group            = $Group.DisplayName
                Name             = $user.DisplayName
                USERPRINCIPALNAME = $user.Mail
                CompanyName      = $user.CompanyName
            }
        } Catch {
            Try {
                $device = Get-MgDevice -DeviceId $member.Id -Property Id, DisplayName | 
                          Select-Object Id, DisplayName

                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Group            = $Group.DisplayName
                    Name             = $device.DisplayName
                    USERPRINCIPALNAME = "N/A"
                    CompanyName      = "N/A"
                }
            } Catch {
                Write-Host "Unable to find user or device for member ID $($member.Id)" -ForegroundColor Red
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Group            = $Group.DisplayName
                    Name             = "Unknown"
                    USERPRINCIPALNAME = "N/A"
                    CompanyName      = "N/A"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

$users | Out-GridView

The PowerShell script above works fine for the Get-MgUser part, however, the Get-MgDevice is not returning any value or empty.
Thank you for the assistance.

My advice is to use the try/catch statement only for unexpected errors and errors you can't control. For this situation, you probably might just use an if/else condition. Besides I question if Get-MgUser returns an error if the user(s) can't be found or just returns an (automation)$Null.

yes, that does make sense. thank you @iRon for the suggestion.

To fetch the users of the Groups (Users/Devices), modify the script like below by using if/else condition as suggested by @iRon:
$GROUP_LIST = Get-MgGroup -Filter "groupTypes/any(c:c eq 'DynamicMembership')" -All:$true | Select-Object Id, DisplayName, Description, GroupTypes

$users = $GROUP_LIST | ForEach-Object {
    $Group = $_
    Write-Host "Processing $($Group.DisplayName)" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    $members = Get-MgGroupMember -GroupId $Group.Id -Property "id,displayName,userPrincipalName,companyName"

    Write-Host "`t [$($Group.DisplayName)] Member count [$($members.Count)]" -ForegroundColor Yellow

    $members | ForEach-Object {
        $member = $_
        $isUser = $false
        $isDevice = $false
        $user = $null
        $device = $null

        Try {
            $user = Get-MgUser -UserId $member.Id -Property Id, DisplayName, Mail, UserPrincipalName, CompanyName -ErrorAction Stop
            $isUser = $true
        } Catch {
            Write-Host "User not found for member ID $($member.Id), trying as device..." -ForegroundColor Magenta
        }

        If (!$isUser) {
            Try {
                $device = Get-MgDevice -DeviceId $member.Id -Property Id, DisplayName -ErrorAction Stop
                $isDevice = $true
            } Catch {
                Write-Host "Device not found for member ID $($member.Id)" -ForegroundColor Red
            }
        }

        If ($isUser) {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Group             = $Group.DisplayName
                Name              = $user.DisplayName
                USERPRINCIPALNAME = $user.Mail
                CompanyName       = $user.CompanyName
            }
        } ElseIf ($isDevice) {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Group             = $Group.DisplayName
                Name              = $device.DisplayName
                USERPRINCIPALNAME = "N/A"
                CompanyName       = "N/A"
            }
        } Else {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Group             = $Group.DisplayName
                Name              = "Unknown"
                USERPRINCIPALNAME = "N/A"
                CompanyName       = "N/A"
            }
        }
    }
}

$users | Out-GridView



I added devices as members of group in testrukdevicegrp:


Thank you @rukmini for the update, yes it is working now.

Glad to know that its working:)
